# Get the cursor position while moving it using MouseAdapter

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Why can't I use mouseMoved() of MouseAdapter to get the cursor position? I want to get that while I'm moving the mouse and show it in the terminal.

How can I do that?

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame {
    public FrameTest() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseMovementListener());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(200, 100);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MouseMovementListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("(" + evt.getX() + ", " + evt.getY() + ")");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameTest();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy. You need to change this line:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseMovementListener());
```

to

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMovementListener());
```